# Changes made on td does not reflect on <a> its child node

Tags: css, fonts, css-tables

I have this table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">Choultry</a></td>
    <td><a href="" >Vegetable verndors</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="" >Decorators</td>
    <td><a href="" >Handicrafts</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and each td has background color white and `font-color:rgb(121,0,0)`. So when I mouseover each td I want the background color to change to rgb(121,0,0) and font-color to change to white. So it alll works fine as long as I don't include `<a>` element i.e hyperlink element.
By default hyperlink element is blue so I assign it to be rgb(121,0,0). When I mouse over td and do my usual reversing of color i.e. background color:rgb(121,0,0) and `color:white` only the background color changes whereas font color does not change it remains rgb(121,0,0) making it invisible. Meaning the changes to td does not reflect its child nodes i.e. `<a>` in this case.

```
.textTable td a
{
    color:rgb(121,0,0);
}

.textTable td:hover
{   
    background-color:rgb(121,0,0);
    color:white;
}
```

These below are diff ways i tried:

1>

```
$(".textTable td").mouseenter(function(){$(".textTable td a").css("color","white");});
$(".textTable td").mouseleave(function(){$(".textTable td a").css("color","rgb(121,0,0)");});
```

here the problem is it will make all  elements inside .textTable td, that is quite obvious.

2>

```
.textTable td:hover
{   
    .textTable td a
    {
         color:white;
    }
    background-color:rgb(121,0,0);
    color:white;
}
```

This was totally stupid.

I know to have a complex code to solve this problem but is there any solution which is very simple so that even child nodes have the changes on their parents reflected?

something like

```
 $(".textTable td").mouseenter(function(){$(".textTable td a").css("color","white");});
    $(".textTable td").mouseleave(function(){$(this).childNodes[0].css("color","rgb(121,0,0)");});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just explicitly select descendants of a hovered element, like this:

```
.textTable td,
.textTable td a {
    color:rgb(121,0,0);
}

.textTable td:hover,
.textTable td:hover a {
    background-color:rgb(121,0,0);
        color:white;
}
```

You don't need javascript. If you like the way your nested rules in your second example look, though, you could look into using SASS or Less, which allow you to do that (more or less)

Comment: hey moopet thanks a lot. I didn know you could do this at all as in hover till a part of element and apply the changes to the next level i.e. .textTable td:hover a{} i didn know even after hover you could traverse more. The solution is perfect.Also guys i found 1 more simple solution with jquery  
    $(".textTable td").mouseenter(function()this.childNodes[0].style.color="white";})
    $(".textTable td").mouseleave(function(){this.childNodes[0].style.color="rgb(121,0,0)";});
    $(".textTable td").click(function(){var x = this.childNodes[0].getAttribute("href"); window.location = x;});

Comment: also guys how to convert this javascript to jquery 
this.childNodes[0].style.color="white";  I tried $(this.childNodes[0].css("color","white")); but it didn work

Comment: Well you can traverse down in jQuery like so: `$(this).find('a').css('color', 'white')` but there's no point - if you can do it in CSS, do it in CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

You didnt add the class to the table. Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/YvbVn/

This

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">Choultry</a></td>
    <td><a href="" >Vegetable verndors</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="" >Decorators</td>
    <td><a href="" >Handicrafts</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Should be

```
<table class="textTable">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">Choultry</a></td>
    <td><a href="" >Vegetable verndors</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="" >Decorators</td>
    <td><a href="" >Handicrafts</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hey the actual code is
<div class = "textTable">
the table follows here
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Is it not enough to add CSS styling for td a:hover too

```
.textTable td a
{
    color:rgb(121,0,0);
}

.textTable td:hover
{   
  background-color:rgb(121,0,0);
  color:white;
}

.textTable td a:hover {
  color:white;

}
```